# Finding the closest span with a specific class inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find the closest `span` with class `error_span`. How can I do that using jQuery?

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="reimburse_price" class="control label">Amount</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="reimburse_price" min="1" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control numberOnly" id="reimburse_price" required>        
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="small text-danger error_span"></span>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript is here

```
$("#reimburse_price").blur(function(){
  checkNumInput("#reimburse_price");
});
```

My jquery function is here

```
function checkNumInput(id){
    if ($(id).val() == "") {
        $(id)[0].setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field');
        $(id).closest("span .error_span").text("Please fill out this field").removeClass("hidden").addClass("text-danger");
    }
}
```

Comment: Closest parent or child? And closest relative to which element?

Comment: Closest relative to?

Comment: Relative to which element?

Comment: Assuming you want to get the span for the input `$(this).parent().closest('div').find('error_span')`

Comment: what u try so far?

Comment: I'm sorry im new here I fixing my question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan closest span to the input reimburse_price

Comment: @healer thanks. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that `closest()` looks at parent elements, yet the `span` you want to find is a child of a parent's sibling to the `input`.

To solve your issue traverse to a common parent of both the `input` and `span` and use `find()` from there. Try this:

```
$("#reimburse_price").blur(function() {
    checkNumInput('#' + this.id);
});

function checkNumInput(id) {
    var $input = $(id);
    if ($input.val() == "") {
        $input.get(0).setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field');
        $input.closest('.form-group').find('.error_span').text("Please fill out this field").toggleClass("hidden text-danger");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked just fine. One last final question will my function work if there is other span inside the div with class form-group?

Comment: If you have more than one element with the `.form-group` class it will still work, but it will set the text and classes on both of those elements

Comment: Is my procedure fine? In my function where i pass the id of the element I will it only find the nearest .form group class?