# Javascript get value of span in neighbouring div

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to retrieve the value of a hidden field (`span class="hiddenfield"`) in a neighbouring div to an input.

I can't just use a getbyelement as I have used the bootstrap grid system to replicate a table like enviroment and so there will be many rows with the same hidden input with different values for each row.

The console just shows a null return for `console.log(stock_id)` rather than the value I can see is in the hiddenfield.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product Code</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Product Description</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">UOI</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-form-label text-right">Avail</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Price £</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Margin</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Qty Rqd</div>
</div>

<% @stock_items.each do |stock| %>
   <%= form_tag new_line_customer_opportunity_sop_header_sop_details_path(@customer,@opportunity, @sop_header), :method => 'get' do %>
   <div style="margin-top: -4px;" class="form-group row form-element row-bottom-margin">
    <div class="col-sm-2"><font size="-1"><%= stock.product_code %></font></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><font size="-1"><%= stock.desc1.titleize %></font></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-right form-group"><font size="-1"><%= stock.uoi %></font></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-right"><font size="-1"><%= strip_trailing_zero(stock.qty_free) %></font></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><%= number_field_tag 'unit_price', number_with_precision(stock.price, :precision => 2), class: 'form-control text-right sales_price' %></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-right margin"><font size="-1"><%= number_to_percentage(((stock.price-stock.cost_sop)/stock.price)*100,precision: 0)%></font></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 stock"><%= number_field_tag 'quantity', 1, class: 'form-control text-right' %></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="hiddenfield"><%= hidden_field_tag 'stock_id', stock.id %></span><%= submit_tag 'Add' %></div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".sales_price").on('change', function(){
 var input = $(this)
 console.log(input)

 var sales_price = input.val()? input.val() : 0;
 console.log(sales_price)

 var stock_id = input.closest('.form-element').find('.hiddenfield').text()
 console.log(stock_id)

})
</script>
```

I am using the logic from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454332/finding-the-closest-span-with-a-specific-class-inside-a-div) that says I should traverse to a common parent of both the `input` and `span` and use `find()` from there - which I thought I had done by using `.form-element`.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: what about this doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you need the hidden field right before the submit button? it's hidden, you can place it right next to the `.sales_price` input and it will be easier to get there. Also, `.hiddenfield` is a span and the input is hidden, `.text()` won't return the value of the field, you should set the class to the hidden field and use `.val()` to get tue value.

Comment: if all you are after is the value of that hidden input, why don't you just use an ID selector? Why all the traversing?

Comment: Hey thanks, I have just edited my question to state what my error is

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod The hiddenfield was added first and then the form built up over time and I never thought of moving it. I have moved it and changed the class of the hiddenfield and it now works.

Comment: I just realised I want to update the contents of the `div class="col-sm-1 text-right margin"` with a calculation so I am going to have to traverse across anyway. I am using `input.closest('form-element').find('.margin').textContent = margin` where `margin` is the output of hte calculation and it also doesn't update

Comment: use the browser inspector to debug your code, maybe `input.closest('form-element').find('.margin')` is not returning the element you want. Also `textContent` is a DOM element property, `find('.margin')` returns a jquery object, to set the text on a jquery object you should use the `.text(...)` method, you are mixing jquery and vanilla javascript code. https://api.jquery.com/text/